# effect of Installing ldap server

Tags: ldap

I am new to the ldap server and I want to install a ldap server in my Ubuntu dedicated server. My ubuntu dedicated server has LAMP and other application servers installed and many websites are being served from that dedicated server.

My question is, Does any application server (like: LAMP, or others) will be affected if I will configure LDAP server in that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Ther application servers (like: LAMP, or others) will not  be affected if you will configure LDAP server.